# Query not giving out null records

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this really simple query. I am unable to figure out why my query is not returning null records.

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.name 
FROM table 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE table1.someid='2' 
AND table2.someid=2 
ORDER BY table1.order
```

I also tried using LEFT JOIN, JOIN, INNER JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN gives an error.

This simple query returns all required values.

```
SELECT table1.name 
FROM table 
WHERE table1.someid='2' 
ORDER BY table1.order
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: You mention getting an error - what error do you get? Are there definitely records existing for table1.someid = 2 AND table2.someid = 2, as in your query? What's your table structure like?

Comment: Oracle style (implicit) joins are INNER JOINs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever you will put in the where clause will force the resultsets to return the rows from the affected table.

In your case you are asking for table2.someid=2, which for mysql means that table2 MUST return a row, with or without a left join.

Solution: use this filter within the left join instead of the where clause

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out which table you're trying to search for "2".  With your two clauses, you are basically turning this into an INNER JOIN query.  You need to search one table or the other.

Make sense?

---

```
SELECT
    table1.name,
    table2.name
FROM
    table
LEFT JOIN
    table2
    ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE
    table1.someid = '2'

-- This clause is basically turning this query into an inner join.
-- AND
--     table2.someid = 2

ORDER BY
    table1.order
```

Comment: Consider fixing the mixed JOIN types. You have `SELECT table1.name, table2.name`, which is an INNER JOIN, and an explicit LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong...

Check this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c368d/1

I've wrote this for you, maybe it helps.

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.cute 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id_table1 = table2.id_table1
ORDER BY table1.name
```